# How to get img src attribute jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of li's in a ul. I am consindering just one li here.

```
 <ul> 
   <li>
    <img
      src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/128/Pear.png"
      alt=""
    />
  </li>
```

Getting a random li into a property(x) using jquery where x is a random number.

```
   var x = $(".list li:eq(" + x + ")");
```

When i Console log x , i get the below li.

```
 <li>
  <img _ngcontent-c3="" alt="" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/128/Pear.png">
 </li>
```

Now i would like to get the src attribute of img tag inside li.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(".list li:eq(" + x + ")").find("img")[0].src`

Comment: `$(".list li:eq(" + x + ") img").attr('src')`

Answer (score 1):

use eq(0) as your desired count

```js
console.log($(".list li:eq(0) img").attr('src'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list"> 
   <li>
    <img
      src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/128/Pear.png"
      alt=""
    />
  </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `.list` class which is not there in ul, i have added it to my example and for src you should use `$(obj).find("img").attr("src")` and this should work!

```js
var x = 0;
var obj = $(".list li:eq(" + x + ")");
console.log($(obj).find("img").attr("src"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list"> 
   <li>
    <img
      src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/128/Pear.png"
      alt=""
    />
  </li>
```